# К какой части речи относится слово "го" из молодёжного сленга?

Tags: сленг

Например, во фразе "Го в Доту, я создал".

Comment: мне кажется, это тот случай, когда Николай дал корректный ответ, но сам вопрос некорректный - к какой части речи относится иностранный глагол, который носитель язык в шутку вставляет в русскую речь?

Comment: @shabunc Да, в английском языке это глагол. В русском -- явно нет, и к какой части речи это слово относится в английском -- в данном случае не играет роли.

Comment: В русском попросту нет такого слова - если будут относительно много употреблять, будет - как произошло с тет-а-тет. А по состоянию на сегодня это спросить как какая часть речи в русском языке "Вамонос" в предложении "Вамонос, амигос".

Comment: @shabunc его уже относительно много употребляют. английский слэнг такой употребительности уже был бы, вероятно, в мерриам-вебстере.

Comment: @shabunc Лично мне приведённая Вами фраза непонятна. А вот "го" очень даже употребляется молодёжью как самостоятельное слово со значением, аналогичным "айда" (как верно заметил Николай), входит в современный слэнг. Смысл употребления его -- в краткости по сравнению с "Давай поиграем в Доту", а не в шутке типа "Иду на коворкинг по крафтовому пиву, понял, что забыл смузи".

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy со лет ит би )

Comment: @shabunc - Там у вас другой случай, это называется «иностранное выражение», это как когда, скажем, латинские изречения в русский текст вставляют, они не являются членами предложения, а вот «го» является.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Го** ничем по формальным признакам не отличается от **айда**. Которое считается междометием.

Comment: я лично всегда воспринимал это слово как глагол со значением "идти"

Comment: @user907860 в исконном языке он, безусловно, этим и является. но не в русском. не бывает глаголов из одного повелительного наклонения.

Comment: То же самое: брысь! марш!

Comment: От "айда" я встречал вежливую форму "айдате". Т.е. не совсем лишено признаков глагола. :)

Answer (score -2):

Это слово - междометие, как и "стоп".

Comment: Я не могу, если честно, понять логику этого ответа. Ответ уже дан, принят, на нём 6 голосов "За" -- для чего давать другой такой же, да ещё и неполный? :)